# Going mad - I need to get grouped results sorted based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, case, greatest-n-per-group

I'm really struggling with this now, been on it for ages and asked two questions on here already!

So, here's a hopefully more defined question.

I have a product database with several thousand products.

Products can be grouped by `item` so as not to display in my search results multiple items that are essentially the same but with different finishes.

So, a simple `select` query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY item
```

This would give me all the products showing just one per item (the idea being that the viewing customer clicks something else to show all the finish options)

I could get my finish options using something like

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(finishes) FROM products GROUP BY item
```

BUt... and here's where I have problems

In my search results pages, the "random" order of the grouping is no good to me. I need to be able to have the displayed item from the group clause depending on the following condtions

```
- If there is no stock of any finish, then display the cheapest option
- If there is stock, then display the cheapest item which is in stock
```

Getting just an ID is no good, I need the full record, so somehow what I need is a condition statement to determine the order in which the grouped records are presented to ensure that the item that I get from the `recordset` meet the criteria above.

I simply cannot work out how to do this, I've tried millions of different `INNER JOIN` and `CASE scenarios, but just can't get it to work.

Here's where I have got to this morning:

```
SELECT * FROM products prod INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id, item, MIN(price) AS minPrice, totalStock, MAX(totalStock) AS maxStock,
    sum(totalStock) as sumTotalStock FROM products WHERE " & whereClause & "
GROUP BY item ORDER BY price) sortedProd ON 
    CASE WHEN sortedProd.sumTotalStock > 0 THEN " ' if there is some of this item in stock
        CASE WHEN sortedProd.minPrice = prod.price AND sortedProd.item = prod.item AND sortedProd.totalStock > 0 THEN  ' check if the item in stock is the cheapest
             sortedProd.minPrice = prod.price AND sortedProd.item = prod.item " ' if the cheapest one is ins tock, display it
        ELSE sortedProd.totalStock > 0  AND sortedProd.item = prod.item END" 'if not display whichever is in stock
    ELSE sortedProd.minPrice = prod.price AND sortedProd.item = prod.item END ' otherwise display the cheapest
GROUP BY prod.item ORDER BY prod.price DESC
```

This is giving me results, but form reason some items are being excluded from the results, and the sorting order is still not correct.

To answer @DRapp below, here's some basic sample data

```
item      |    price     |     finish         | totalStock
```

---

```
item 1    |     £1       |       red          |     2
item 1    |     £1       |       blue         |     1
item 1    |     £1.50    |       blue & red   |     1
```

---

```
item 2    |     £2       |       red          |     0
item 2    |     £3       |       blue         |     1
```

---

```
item 3    |     £3.50    |       blue & red   |     1
item 3    |     £1       |       red          |     0
item 3    |     £2       |       blue         |     1
```

---

```
item 4    |     £4.50    |       blue & red   |     1
```

---

```
item 5    |     £1.50    |       blue         |     0
item 5    |     £2.50    |       green        |     0
item 5    |     £0.50    |       orange       |     0
```

The result I'd like to see is:

- **item 1, red** (sumTotalStock = 4) - 'red and blue are both cheapest & in stock. Either result shown is fine, but to be 100% perfect, show red as the stock is greatest
- **item 2, blue** (sumTotalStock = 1) -' blue is the only finish in stock
- **item 3, blue** (sumTotalStock = 2) - 'display blue as it's cheapest in stock
- **item 4, blue & red** (sumTotalStock = 1) -'there are no finish options, so just show this one regardless of stock/price
- **item 5, orange** (sumTotalStock = 0) - 'none in stock, but show orange as it's cheapest.

Obviously there is more data to actually display than just finish and price, product description etc also, which may vary depending on finish, hence I do need to get the full record, but this data example should explain the principle.

Comment: in Oracle, I would write a USER DEFINED AGGREGATE FUNCTION - not sure about mysql.  maybe write a function that takes the item as a param, then returns a string of the finishes.

Comment: Pretty sure this is an example of the greatest-n-per-group problem. Have a search through the SO tagged questions to see some solutions that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group

Comment: Can you dump some of the sample data, including those with no finish, and samples of pricing and such.  Then show what you would LIKE the final results to be (in case the answer by Martijn is not the final for you)

Comment: @DRapp OK, I'll have a go at Martijn's answer now and post more detail here if required.

Comment: @DRapp I've added some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want using a "simple" left join and no nested selects; your sort criteria make the query look a bit bulky though :)

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM Products p1
LEFT JOIN Products p2
  ON p1.item=p2.item AND
     (IF(p1.totalstock,1,0) < IF(p2.totalstock,1,0) OR
      (IF(p1.totalstock,1,0) = IF(p2.totalstock,1,0) AND
       p1.price > p2.price) OR
      (p1.price = p2.price AND 
       p1.totalstock < p2.totalstock) OR
      (p1.price = p2.price AND 
       p1.totalstock = p2.totalstock AND
       p1.id > p2.id))
WHERE p2.id IS NULL
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b6e1/5).

Comment: That looks similar to what I was trying to achieve, could you explain `WHERE p2.id IS NULL`? Also, is this where to put my main search criteria `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @JamieHartnoll Basically it sorts using the `LEFT JOIN` by trying to match each p1 up with a "better" p2. If there's no better p2, then p2.id is NULL. Do you have a typical WHERE condition to show?

Comment: Excellent, this appears to be working! For querying an item I am doing `WHERE p1.item='SEARCH TEXT'` and this seems to work, the most common other application I'll need is to query the category field, brands and also, as you mention, price (I excluded categories from original question as it wasn't part of the problem) so for these I'd need to put in `p1` and `p2` as per your comment?

Comment: Oh, you've chnaged your comment! `where` would typically be something like `where category = 'CAT REQUIRED' AND subcategory='SUB CAT'` and in some cases there'd be a text based search which would be `WHERE item LIKE '%SEARCH TEXT%'` all WHERE clauses would be finished off with `AND display = '1'` to filter out items which should not be displayed.

Comment: This has done the trick. My only question now is, would the other answer suggested have been faster?

Comment: Argh, I do have a further problem! I need to get a sumTotalStock, I'm not getting that at the moment using `sum(totalStock) as sumTotalStock`

Comment: Ah, sorted, I did another `JOIN` like this `LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, MAX(price) as maxPrice, count(id) As Variants, sum(totalStock) as sumTotal FROM Products GROUP BY item) P0 on p1.item=P0.item` to get the rest of the data I needed. I'd still be interested on any views on efficiency with this method though...

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you each item with its lowest price. You could join this again against your items table to get the rest of the details, joining on item and lowest_price. If prices are equal you will need some sort tie-braker which to select. Is this enough for you?

```
SELECT COALESCE(instock.price, allItems.price) as lowest_price, item FROM
(SELECT MIN(price) as minprice, item FROM products WHERE totalstock > 0 GROUP BY item) as instock
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT MIN(price) as minprice, item FROM products GROUP BY item) as allItems
ON instock.item = allItems.item
```

Edit: MySQL doesn't have a full outer join. Changed to a right outer join, and remove the condition from out stock so that it has all items.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now. I'm very vague on using `join` as until this morning I never have! I'll give it a go though!

Comment: Um, I'm getting an SQL Syntax error in your code, having tried adding this into my `select` as follows: `SELECT * FROM products prod INNER JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(instock.price, outstock.price) as lowest_price, item FROM (SELECT MIN(price) as minprice, item FROM products WHERE totalstock > 0 GROUP BY item) as instock FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT MIN(price) as minprice, item FROM products WHERE totalstock <= 0 GROUP BY item) as outstock ON instock.item = outstock.item) sortedProd ON sortedProd.item` I get `syntax error near 'FULL OUTER JOIN (`

Comment: Ugh, mysql, I forgot, doesn't have a full outer join. I'll fix the query for it

Comment: I tried removing the `Full` keyword, but that didn't work either, Joachim Isaksson's answer seems to be working. Would your be faster?

Comment: no, I fixed the statement in my answer, going for a right join, and losing the <= 0 clause